# Can the open mapping theorem fail if $T:E\to F$ is not continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

The open map theorem states that if $E$ and $F$ are two Banach spaces and $T:E\to F$ is a continuous surjective linear map, then $T$ is an open map.

Is well known that [if $F$ is not Banach, then the theorem can fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793127/open-mapping-theorem-can-fail-if-codomain-is-not-banach). The same can occur if [$E$ is not Banach](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44716/counterexample-for-the-open-mapping-theorem).

But if $T$ is not continuous can such theorem fail? Someone has a counterexample of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space such that we can take $\|\cdot\|_1, \|\cdot\|_2$ to be two complete norms on $X$ that are inequivalent. Consider the identity map $\operatorname{Id}: (X, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (X, \|\cdot\|_2)$.

Inequivalence of the norms is exactly the same as saying that neither of $\operatorname{Id}$ and $\operatorname{Id}^{-1}$ is bounded. That is, $\operatorname{Id}$ is a discontinuous linear bijection that is not open.

Comment: Hmm, very nice thanks. But I have one question: Given a Banach space $(X,||x||_1)$ is it a proposition that there is another inequivalent complete norm $||\cdot||_2$ on $X$?

Comment: If $X$ is infinite dimensional then yes, though it requires some machinery (in particular, you need the axiom of choice somewhere). One way to get $\|\cdot\|_2$ is to take a discontinuous linear functional $\phi$ on $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$ and choose any $y \in X$ such that $\phi(y) = 1$. It then turns out that if $Tx = x - 2\phi(x)y$ then $\|x\|_2 = \|Tx \|_1$ defines an inequivalent complete norm. Existence of an unbounded functional is still non-trivial but can be proven by defining the behaviour of the functional on a Hamel basis (existence of a Hamel basis is where I use the axiom of choice).